Does lambda pull a batch events only include one group ID from SQS?
I am using SQS FIFO queue with lambda to process events. The group id in the sqs makes sure all events with the same group id are in order. The lambda pulls from this sqs on a batch size maximum to 10. My question is when the lambda pulls a batch of events, would the batch includes events for 1 group id? Is it possible that a lambda pulls a batch of events cross multiple group ids?
